# Connection between login page and register

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to `php`, I'm trying to link the login page and register page. Once I press the login button it goes directly to the linked page although I enter wrong password.

I tried to solve it by putting `mysqlinumrows`. The result after login is still in the login page . I've tried to fix it, but can't. I hope someone will help me to reduce my stress by knowing my fault in the code below I attach.

### Code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['message'] = '';
    $mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','accounts');

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if ($_POST['password']== $_POST['confirmpassword']) {

            $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $profile_path = $mysqli->real_escape_string('images/'.$_FILES['profile']['name']);


            if (preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['profile']['type'])) {

                if (copy($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'],$profile_path)){
                    $_SESSION['username'] =$username;
                    $_SESSION['profile'] =$profile_path;

                    $sql ="INSERT INTO users(username,email,password,profile)"
                    ."VALUES ('$username','$email','$password','$profile_path')";       

                    if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
                              $_SESSION['message'] =  'Registration successful!
                              Added $username to the database!';
                         header("location:RegisterLogin.php");
                          }
                          else {
                              $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be added to the database!";
                }
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['message'] = "file failed!";

            }
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Please only upload GIF,JPG, or PNG images!";
        }
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "two password do not match!";
        }
        }

    ?> 

    (Login Form)
    <?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['message']=''; 
    $mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','accounts');


    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE  username ='$username' AND password=$password";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

            if(mysqli_affected_rows($result) == 1){
                  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                 $_SESSION['message'] =  "Registration successful!";
        header("location:Welcome.php");
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Login Failed!"; 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you can also post your forms so we can determine the problem easily.

Comment: Did it print the $_SESSION['message']?

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `select` query in login page to `$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE  username ='$username' AND password='$password' ";` Add single quotes to password variable

Answer (score 0):

First you must have form tag. try this format

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" name="login">
</form>
```

And for your PHP code:

```html
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
            $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE  username ='$username' AND password=$password";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

            if(mysqli_affected_rows($result) == 1){
                  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                 $_SESSION['message'] =  "Registration successful!";
        header("location:Welcome.php");
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Login Failed!"; 
        }
    }
```

If It's not your problem then comment it below. I'll help you.